# GTK module can only sometimes be found

Tags: gtk, vmware-workstation

When I try to install VMWare Workstation on Ubuntu 14.04 I get the following warnings:

```
(vmware-installer.py): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I ignore those and install anyway, the warnings reoccurs when running the vmplayer

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

I googled it and a lot of suggestions were made to install some packages, which i did

```
libcanberra-gtk-module
libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
libcanberra-gtk3-module:i386
libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

All possible versions are available now (Note that I needed to run 'sudo updatedb' for locate and vmplayer to find them)

```
user@machine:~/Desktop$ locate libcanberra-gtk-module.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so
```

After installing 'libcanberra-gtk-module' (gtk-2.0 64bit version) the vmplayer command found the module, but the installer still can't find it. Should I worry? Or just ignore since I will probably never use that installer again? Also how come it finds the module in the one case, but not in the other?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as I was attempting to run Wireshark after an update and upgrade on Kali rolling system. Wireshark is completely wiped out and I haven't even had a chance to use it or learn anything yet. I have never heard of these files or modules before and know nothing about them or how to get them back.

Comment: Hi. By posting as an 'answer' the site expects that you answer or try to answer the question asked. If you have your own question, ask it separately or just give a comment. Thanks and welcome.

Comment: No idea, as still trying to correct update and upgrade problems that have surfaced on latest installation of Linux Mint. Update Manager now does not update properly or download any packages properly; /usr/bin/sbin and dpkg errors now plague me for the moment?  dpkg error no (2)?